# Probability of a team winning a 64 team, single elimination tournament?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

What is the most efficient way to calculate the probability that a team winning a 64 team single elimination tournament, given that...

- You can easily calculate head-to-head probabilities for each team

As you can imagine, calculating first round probabilities are not difficult. It does, however, become complicated when considering the permutations after the first round. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any pattern to the H2H probabilities? Otherwise, it's just a pain

Comment: There is no pattern, unfortunately. If it helps, I'm trying to recreate something like this: https://kenpom.com/blog/2019-ncaa-tournament-probabilities/ This model is my go-to for NCAA brackets but the method was altered in 2017, so I was trying to replicate this method to prior years.

Comment: You need all intermediate results of potential opponents surviving till they meet you. Which means that you need to simulate practically all outcomes. Sprcial fun arises because sometimes $A$ has an advantage over $B$ and $B$ over $C$, but $C$ has an advantage over $A$

Comment: There are ${64 \choose 2}=2016$ head-to-head possibilities but $\frac{64!}{2^{63}} >10^{70}$ possibilities for how the tournament may be arranged.  So a good approach would be to find all $2016$ probabilities (actually double that as the other team may win) and simulate enough tournaments to get a good view of the likely outcomes